# How do I setup a Heroku app with app.json?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am learning about Heroku's `app.json` and `app-setups` features. I added an `app.json` to my repo's root directory and configured it to setup add-ons, env vars, etc.

Now I am trying to figure out the steps for someone who has cloned my repo locally from GitHub and made some edits, to deploy it to Heroku, and for the `app.json` to be processed.

Heroku's [help article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api#creating-an-app-setup) gives an example, but I feel maybe I am missing a simpler way, because (1) it uses cURL, which many of my users might not have installed, (2) it relies on the repo being at a publicly accessible URL, rather than locally, and (3) it's more verbose than typical Heroku commands.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but you can look at Heroku Button [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button). It is definitely simpler. It does not use curl and can be used with private repositories.